# GetUserAvailability with RoomLists

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

EDIT 1: The '...could not be found in store' message is effectively a permission problem on the Room. The user must be granted the **Reviewer** privilege.

EDIT 2: CalendarEvents collection is empty because is seems to contains only busy information. If I put a meeting in a room at the time where I ask for suggestion, it is returned.

I'm trying to use the Room Finder capability of Exchange 2010 Web Services (EWS).

I have two problems:

1. This [MS sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx) gives you the impression that you're about to get that. The pictures shows a request with rooms but the code does not... This should be easy to add a new attendee that is of type Room or a RoomList.
2. Adding a Room to the code leads to nothing when asking free busy information. CalendarEvents collection is empty.

   ```
   foreach (AttendeeAvailability availability in results.AttendeesAvailability)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Availability information for {0}:\n", attendees[i].SmtpAddress);

       foreach (CalendarEvent calEvent in availability.CalendarEvents)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("\tBusy from {0} to {1} \n", calEvent.StartTime.ToString(), calEvent.EndTime.ToString());
       }

       i++;
   }
   ```

Furthermore, asking for appointment(s) for a specific Room:

```
CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8));
       FolderId folderID = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, roomAddress.Address);
       FindItemsResults roomAppts = service.FindAppointments(folderID, calendarView);
```

Gives me an error :
'The specified folder could not be found in the store'

I do not know if this is a permission issue lying underneath...

I'm testing this code against an Office 365 account. If I use Outlook (Mac version) I can't see the Rooms, which seems to point a permission problem. But going with Outlook Web, I can see the rooms and save calendar events.

Very strange.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> > Gives me an error : 'The specified folder could not be found in the store'

This error means you don't have at least reviewer rights to the folder in question.

GetUserAvailblity is different from using FindAppointments because it uses the FreeBusy information the is published by the mailbox. Therefore it will use FreeBusy permissions https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2865291/how-to-set-free-busy-permissions-in-exchange-management-shell-in-offic the most restrictive of which (FreeBusyOnly) will only return the AvailabilityData (eg free or busy). To return the CalendarEvents requires at least LimitedDetails.

The place to start would be to ensure you have at least LimitedDetails on the calendars in question. The other thing to do would be enable tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx and look at the raw data that is being returned (eg that would show if its actually just returning the availability information).

Comment: I already have the Reviewer Persmission which seems to be higher than LimitedDetails. Am I wrong ?

Comment: The error tells a different story maybe try using the ewseditor to eliminate issue with your code.

Comment: May be my edits are not clear. No more error message. No suggestions though, which is the purpose of the room finder. About EwsEditor, I'm on a Mac so this is not an option.

Comment: One thing you can try is if this is working in OWA okay is use the Developer tool in the web browser and have a look at what request are being made. OWA in 2010 is using EWS so you can see the requests and responses that is makes then compare that to the requests and responses in the code.

Comment: It seems that OWA is using its own implementation of the room finder... It does not call EWS but Owa's GetUSerAvailabilityInternal